# Randomly Get Data from Sharepoint List then Automaticaly assign to every registered user

Tags: sharepoint-online

im new to sharepoint online, there is somethings i would like to ask.

1. I have Sharepoint lists consisting of user_id
2. I have a registration form.

here's the thing, i have a registration form, then after their registration and confirmed their enrollment, Sharepoint will automatically send an email to user their user_id (from the Sharepoint lists (randomly)).

Answer (score 1):

You can design a [Microsoft flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/flow/get-started/create-your%20first-flow) that sends a notification message to registered users with their IDs. Configure the flow to start automatically on adding new items to the SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

MS flow can easily do this work. A flow triggered when a new item is created in that list(which means a new form is submitted) will be enough.

I add an if condition in the sample flow for the possible need of "confirmed their enrollment". If it works, the flow will send the email. You can directly use the email address of the creator or other people.

The engineer email is a people column which can be filled by users. So it is very flexible for you to handle the process. 
[image]